# Rails/MySQL query where a third-level joined ID doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, join

Ive got the following models/associations:

```
class Property
  has_many :jobs
end

class Job
  belongs_to :property
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task
  belongs_to :job
  has_one :service
end

class Service
  belongs_to :task
end
```

I'm trying to write a query where it returns properties that do not have jobs with tasks with services in an array of ID's. So:

```
Property.joins(jobs: { tasks: :service }).where('services.id NOT IN (?)', params[:service_ids])
```

But what that is returning is basically any property that has at least one job that has at least one task that doesn't have those service ID's.

What I'm trying to get it to return is properties that have no jobs at all with tasks with those services, but I'm not sure how to go about that?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get all the job ids that have tasks with the services selected            
job_ids = Job.joins( tasks: :service ).where(
  "services.id IN (?)", params[:service_ids]
).select(:property_id).distinct

# Return only properties that do not have those jobs
properties = properties.where.not(id: job_ids)
```